# Reorganizing a list of tuples into lists of floats

Tags: python

Say I have in python a list of tuples

```
list1 = [(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3)]
```

If I want to separate them into a list of all the 1 position values, 2 position values and 3 position values I would do:

```
ones = [tuple[0] for tuple in list1]
twos = [tuple[1] for tuple in list1]
threes = [tuple[2] for tuple in list1]
```

This sort of way can become very cumbersome the more elements each tuple in that list will have. Is there a cleaner way to do this possibly using the zip method or a reverse of it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `zip` for this:

```
list(zip(*list1))
```

output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

As @paoloaq noted, you can unpack these into separate lists:

```
ones, two, threes = list(zip(*list1))
```

or if you want lists instead of tuples:

```
ones, two, threes = map(list, list(zip(*list1)))
```

*Sidenote: try avoiding variable names like `list` and `tuple`.*

Comment: To have three separate lists:  ```ones, two, threes = [list(l) for l in zip(*list1)] ```